# Memoization-based puzzle solution - sums in a triangle

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm, memoization

I am trying to solve a problem at [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN). As I am new to programming, I am not familiar with dynamic programming. However, I do know the basics of recursion and memoization. Hence I implemented a solution to the above mentioned problem. The problem with my solution is that it exceeds the time limit given. As far as I can guess, the problem seems to be with my memoization logic. Please help me optimize the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vector1D ;
typedef vector<vector1D > vector2D ; // Two Dimensional vector

int rownum;
int noOfCalls = 0;
vector2D a;
vector2D cache; // The cache to implement memoization

int solve (int i, int j)
{

    int t1,t2,total;
    if( i > rownum-1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (cache[i][j] != 0 && ( i < 50) && ( j < 50)) { //for small values use memoization
            return cache[i][j];
        }
        t1 = solve(i+1,j);
        t2 = solve(i+1,j+1);
        total = max(t1,t2) + a[i][j];
        cache[i][j] = total;//store in cache
    }
    return total;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tries;
    cin>>tries;
    while(tries--) {
        cin>>rownum;
        int temp = rownum;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rownum ; i++) {
            a.push_back(vector1D(rownum,0));//initialize memory
        }
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cache.push_back(vector1D(10,0));//initialize cache
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j <= i; j++) {
                cin>>a[i][j];
            }
        }
    cout<<solve(0,0)<<endl;//call the solving function
    cache.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your solution overall looks Ok. You should extend the memoization for all values. Max no of lines is <=100 and `100X100` vector is Ok to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General Comments.

I hate your use of global variables.

```
int rownum;
int noOfCalls = 0;
vector2D a;
vector2D cache; // The cache to implement memoization
```

I suppose it is an attempt at better performance.

The test for j here is redundant:

```
if (cache[i][j] != 0 && ( i < 50) && ( j < 50))
```

If i is smaller than 50 then j can not be greater than 50. If i is greater than 50 then the test will fail and there is no need to test what the value of j is.

#### Bugs

```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < rownum ; i++) {
        a.push_back(vector1D(rownum,0));//initialize memory
    }
```

As you never clear `a` the size increases for every puzzle.
This can become quite expensive as `a` will continuously keep breaking its buffer and have to be re-allocated (copying all those internal arrays).

#### Speed

If you are solely going for speed then `operator>>` is about half the speed of `scanf` as it (operator>>) takes into account a lot of local stuff that is not done with scanf.

Your recursive algorithm is computing some spots multiple times.

```
// Your Triangle
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15

// Number of times each spot is hit with recursion
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

As you can see some of the spots in the center bottom of the triangle are being hit many many times by recursion when you only want to hit each location once. Thus an iterative solution is probably better.

You are using a 2D array to represent the triangle which requires two de-references (which can be inefficient (but without measuring I am not convinced this is a major issue)). Rather than do that use a 1-D array given the number of rows n you can quickly compute the number of elements in the triangle as `n*(n+1)/2` and thus re-size the array in one statement. Element access for a child of m is `m+row(m)+0` and `m+row(m)+1` (note the calculation of row(m) does not need to be done each time you can keep track of this as you increment m).

Answer (score 1):

If your priority is performance with this, in addition to having a memoizing cache for up to the size of about the L1 cache - maybe 4K or so, I'd also get rid of the use of the vector of vector.

You're spending a disproportionate amount of time in your vectors' [] operator() functions which will cause an over-abundance of stack pushes and context switches - you're using that operator in at least four places in each pass through solve() - six when not cached already.  You can see this if you profile your code.  I'd keep it to a vector with dynamically allocated columns and use only pointer arithmetic so that all accesses are happening from the same stack frame in solve().  I'd pre-calculate base pointers in advance and use those as much as possible in the pointer calculations using the bitwise << sizeof(int) to traverse.

I would also stay local and convert your max(t1,t2) call to use a bit-twiddle trick so that total is now:

```
total = t1 ^ ((t1 ^ t2) & -(t1 < t2)) + *paij;
```

where *paij is the dereferenced arithmetically calc'ed pointer instead of a[i][j].  That should keep the pipeline full more often.

To get to the next level from there, I would probably move from recursion to an iterative approach if you're not married to recursion.

That should buy you some performance gain, although more could be done depending on your machine configuration.

#### Edit: Test for speed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/time.h> 

using namespace std; 

inline int getmax( int a, int b ) { if ( a < b ) return b; else return a; }
int main()
{
    time_t timev;
    timeval t1, t2; 
    double elapsed_time; 
    const unsigned int RUNL = 1000000000; 

    int i = 0; 
    int j = 1; 
    int k = 1; 
    int total;

    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
        total = j ^ ( ( j ^ k ) & -( j < k ) );
        k ^= 1;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
    elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
    cout << "Elapsed time for the bitop was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl;
    i = 0;
    k = 1;
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
        total = max( j, k ); k ^= 1;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
    elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
    cout << "Elapsed time for the stl call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl;
    i = 0;
    k = 1;
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
        total = getmax( j, k ); k ^= 1;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
    elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
    cout << "Elapsed time for the getmax call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl; 

}
```

#### Edit (Edit) Fixed Speed Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void printTime(int total, std::string const& name, timeval& t1, timeval& t2)
{
    double elapsed_time;

    elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
    elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;

    std::cout << "Result(" << total << ") Elapsed time for the " << name << " call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << std::endl;
}


inline int getmax( int a, int b ) { if ( a < b ) return b; else return a; }

int main()
{
    timeval t1, t2;
    const unsigned int RUNL = 1000000000;

    std::cout << "LoadData" <<  std::endl;
    std::vector<int> data(RUNL);
    for(int loop=0;loop < RUNL;++loop)
    {
        data[loop]  = rand();
    }
    std::cout << "LoadData DONE" << std::endl;


    int j = data[0];
    int k;
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for(int loop = 1;loop < RUNL;++loop)
    {
        k = data[loop];
        j = j ^ ( ( j ^ k ) & -( j < k ) );
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime(j, "BIT TWIDDLE", t1, t2);

    j = data[0];
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for(int loop = 1;loop < RUNL;++loop)
    {
        k = data[loop];
        j = max( j, k );
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime(j, "std::max", t1, t2);

    j = data[0];
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for(int loop = 1;loop < RUNL;++loop)
    {
        k = data[loop];
        j = getmax( j, k );
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime(j, "inline max", t1, t2);
}
```

Results:

```
> g++ -O3 x.cpp
> ./a.out
LoadData
LoadData DONE
Result: total( 2147483645) Elapsed time for the BIT TWIDDLE call was: 1968.2 ms

Result: total( 2147483645) Elapsed time for the std::max call was: 1170.83 ms

Result: total( 2147483645) Elapsed time for the inline max call was: 1178.05 ms
```

It's easy to see why the optimizer runs so much faster than the bit hack from this code from between the gettimeofday calls):

```
STLMAX
    movl    28(%esp), %ecx
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $1, %eax
    .p2align 4,,7
L34:
    movl    (%ecx,%edx,4), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %ebx
    cmovl   %edx, %ebx
    addl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    $1000000000, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    jne L34
    leal    40(%esp), %eax
    movl    $0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)


BIT HACK
    movl    28(%esp), %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $1, %edx
    .p2align 4,,7
L25:
    movl    (%edi,%eax,4), %ecx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    %ebx, %ecx
    setg    %al
    xorl    %ebx, %ecx
    negl    %eax
    addl    $1, %edx
    andl    %ecx, %eax
    xorl    %eax, %ebx
    cmpl    $1000000000, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    jne L25
    leal    40(%esp), %eax
    movl    $0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
```

Basically two effective instructions in the loop doing the actual max in optimized STL compiler compared with seven for the bit hack.  Lesson learned.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Code for hasZeroByte which gave about 2.5x improvement for the bit hack over the other two under -O3 optimization conditions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void printTime(int total, std::string const& name, timeval& t1, timeval& t2)
{
    double elapsed_time;

    elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
    elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;

    std::cout << "Result(" << total << ") Elapsed time for the " << name << " call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << std::endl;
}


inline bool checkZbyte1( int a ) 
{ 
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof( int ); i++ )
    {
      if ( !( 0xff & a ) )
        return true;
      else
        a >>= 8;
    }
  return false;
}

inline bool checkZbyte2( int a ) 
{ 
  if ( !( 0xff & a ) || !( 0xff00 & a )  || !( 0xff0000 & a )  || !( 0xff000000 & a ) )
    return true;
  return false;
}

int main()
{
    timeval t1, t2;
    const unsigned int RUNL = 100000000;

    std::cout << "LoadData" <<  std::endl;
    std::vector<int> data(RUNL);
    for(int loop=0; loop < RUNL; ++loop)
      data[loop]  = rand();
    std::cout << "LoadData DONE" << std::endl;

    int j;
    int count = 0;

    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for(int loop = 0; loop < RUNL ;++loop)
    {
      if ( checkZbyte1( data[loop] ) )
        count++;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime( count, "inline version #1", t1, t2 );

    count = 0;
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for( int loop = 0; loop < RUNL; ++loop )
    {
      if ( checkZbyte2( data[loop] ) )
        count++;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime( count, "inline version #2", t1, t2 );

    count = 0;
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    for( int loop = 0; loop < RUNL; ++loop )
    {
      j = data[loop];
      if ( ~( ( ( (j & 0x7F7F7F7F ) + 0x7F7F7F7F ) | j ) | 0x7F7F7F7F ) )
        count++;
    }
    gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );
    printTime( count, "BIT HACK", t1, t2 );

}
```

Comment: Unless your compiler is extremely ancient/stupid, it will generate better code for `max` than any bit-twidding hack you come up with.  Otherwise these are good ideas :-)

Comment: I think bit twiddling is silly. Also I am not sure I agree that operator[] is a problem. This is simply `returns base[index]` and as such is probably inlined and is no more expensive than a normal array access. If you are saying that the 2D array is the problem then maybe.

Comment: hmm.. Why are bit hacks silly?  I just ran 3 different cases of max using 1Billion of each all in identical loops.  The results:

Comment: Thing cut me off for taking to long... ironic... the results:

  bit hack max as above: 3.052s
  stl max() call:        4.238s
  my own getmax() call:  4.470s

the results were consistent.  I'm using cygwin with gcc 4.5 on a quad 2.5GHz Dell M6400.  Try it yourself... I don't think we could disregard an improvement of 29%.

Comment: They are silly because the compiler will always do as well and usually better. If you have found a new optimization to max (unlikely) then it will be introduced into the compiler and the next evolution of the compiler will be just as quick as your code. Post your code. :-) we will see how well it really does.

Comment: Loki - I didn't invent or discover this bit hack.  It's well known.  I think you'll find this link rocks: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax 

The reason why this is much faster is as I mentioned: it's inline and completely arithmetic with no branches and no context switches due to stack pushes.  Branches will flush the CPU pipe, which with intel processors these days are about 16 deep.  This will help keep the CPU pipes full and continuous.  I don't know that the compiler can be told to use this optimization in any way.

Comment: Guess what. Compiler writers can read as well (thus if it is well known (and quicker) it is being used already (automatically)). I don't believe your results are legitimate. Please as requested above **Post Your Code** so we can validate.

Comment: 1st of four parts:

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

inline int getmax( int a, int b )
{
  if ( a < b )
    return b;
  else
    return a;
}

int main()
{
  time_t timev;
  timeval t1, t2;
  double elapsed_time;

  const unsigned int RUNL = 1000000000;

  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;
  int k = 1;
  int total;

Comment: gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
  while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
      total = j ^ ( ( j ^ k ) & -( j < k ) );
      k ^= 1;
    }
  gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );

  elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
  elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
  cout << "Elapsed time for the bitop was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl;

  i = 0;
  k = 1;

Comment: gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
  while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
      total = max( j, k );
      k ^= 1;
    }
  gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );

  elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
  elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
  cout << "Elapsed time for the stl call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl;

Comment: i = 0;
  k = 1;

  gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
  while ( i++ < RUNL )
    {
      total = getmax( j, k );
      k ^= 1;
    }
  gettimeofday( &t2, NULL );

  elapsed_time = ( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec ) * 1000.0;
  elapsed_time += ( t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec ) / 1000.0;
  cout << "Elapsed time for the getmax call was: " << elapsed_time << " ms\n" << endl;

}

Comment: You can delete the comments I added the code to your question. I will take a closer look this afternoon.

Comment: I just tried it again with -O3 ... you'll need to declare k and total volatile int so the optimizer doesn't optimize them out on MSVC... on gcc -O3 will optimize the variables out and stl max isn't allowing a volatile cast, so nothing will happen.  -O1 will actually optimize... and ... you're right.  I see no real difference between the bit hack and the stl call for max.  In fact, in another, less contrived case I'm working on right now, max was faster than the bit hack.  I wasn't optimizing when I tested the code.  I guess max is too utilized for compiler people to mess that one up.

Comment: I fixed a couple of problems with your test. And re-ran. The test consistently show that the bit twiddle is about half the speed of std::max.

Comment: What happens if you move the bit hack to run as the last test.  My concern is that you're suffering a performance hit for the first test due to the initial caches misses at every level for the first test, and many fewer for the subsequent tests.  My tests showed that all three tests wound up about the same for all three regardless of compiler on this one intel machine - given optimization.

Comment: No difference (ie bit twiddling twice as slow). The cache has already been warmed up by the init (setting everything to rand()). So you get the same cache effects on each test. But I changed the order and got the same results.

Comment: But this just supports my theory. The compiler is using the best max algorithm for the platform. On my platform (Mac/gcc) it has a faster implementation; on your platform it is the same (may us bit twiddling underneath). The point being the compiler will always have the fastest version you are not going to beat it. If you do beat it then tell the compiler vendor and the implementation will be updated for your platform and next version of the compiler will equal the hand coded version thus you will never beat the compiler (especially in the long run).

Comment: Performance could be better in bit hacks in some useful functions not in the library (unlike this one) since the compiler wouldn't know what's intended in aggregate. Esp. in hacks that avoid branches. Like would the optimizer do better in assembling the obvious method than: // 32-bit word check if any 8-bit byte in it is 0:  bool hasZeroByte = ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F); (I don't have time now to check) ...

Comment: **Totally disagree**. The test we did just proved that your thinking is not correct. That was the whole point of this conversation. You will always loose to a compiler. Any decent optimizing compiler already does all the optimizations that you can think off. If you think of an optimization that is not in the compilers vocab (**very very** unlikely) it will be added the next iteration of the compiler. Thus you will never beat it and your code will be unmaintainable so a **DOUBLE** loss.

Comment: See toy code post above for has ZeroByte = ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F).  Even with -O3 optimization this got 2.5x better on my setup.  I used two inlined variants of the alternatives. I agree with you, if it is better than the compiler can do, it could be rolled into a library. But not all bit hacks could reasonably be added.  These are one-liners - maybe just good to educate people on what is out there and where, and then add to that store of knowledge which ones are useless and less efficient than what the libs/compiler opt will provide

Answer (score 0):

Why only use memoization for "small" values of `i` and `j`?

Without memoization, your program runs in exponential time.  The problem, which memoization intends to solve, is that you tend to compute the same value many times along the way.

So you memoize some of the values, to save time.  On those areas of the table you aren't memoizing, you still suffer the exponential slowdown.  And you're only memoizing 1/4 of your domain.